# Enlarging objects contours in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

From my image, I created a binary mask marking some objects (up to three-four objects on one image).
Let's say, that those marked objects on my mask have a total surface field of `X`.

Now I want to enlarge their contours so that the space that will remain (black area) will have surface area of `X`.
If they take more than `50%` of image then I want to leave it unchanged.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of erode/dilate? Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar. I was thinking about dilatation, but I cannot explicitly specify to which size I can enlarge object through dilatation right? The dilatation will make my objects bigger, the problem is I have a strict rule about how big I want them to be.

Comment: Yes you're right. You can tune the size of the convolution filter but you can't know in advance the surface your objects will be. The only way to know that is to apply dilate and compute surfaces... so you could do that in a loop until you reach a satisfying precision. I can't come up with a better solution and I don't feel it's what you need, so I'm not posting it as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following. Compute the distance transform M of the mask. Then take some sensible distance d > 0 as a starting value. Then do a binary search, i.e. if M < d is less than X percent of the total image, set d = 2d if it is more than X percent set d = d/2. Repeat this a couple of times until the precision is good enough for your needs.

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar, but I would compute a cumulative histogram of the distance transform, then you can easily find the threshold at which the background is a certain percentage of all pixels.

Comment: By performing distance transform I can evaluate the size of my mask (non zero pixels). right? Then I can find this threshold, but what next? How can I use this threshold value? user3726947, what should I do if I find this "d" variable,  I am not sure, that I understand you correctly

Comment: I think the histogram approach Cris proposed is better than the binary search, so I would advise you to try that.

Comment: Ok, but could you explain it more specifically, I am new to OpenCV. What should I do with this histogram? What operations should I use to enlarge my contours?

Comment: @KarolŻurowski: You need to compute the distance transform (DT) within the background (i.e. distance to the nearest "on" pixel in the mask). Any threshold of this DT, inverted, is identical to a dilation of the mask. The higher the threshold, the larger the dilation. In a sense, the DT contains all possible dilations. It is a great way to examine many dilations with different sizes at the same time.